# Autogrowing ENUMs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, enums

I want to optimize tables having `VARCHAR` columns that count only few -- most of time less than tens, sometimes hundreds  -- different values. So I wish to convert the columns to `ENUM`s, the point is that I can't anticipate on the values themselves, so I wish to build them on-the-fly, whenever necessary.

Unfortunately, it appears that that MySQL won't throw an error when inserting a value that do not exist, but instead will store `NULL`.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE `enumed` (
  `col` ENUM( 'a', 'b' )
);

INSERT INTO `enumed` ( `col`) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO `enumed` ( `col`) VALUES ('z');
```

Will store a row with `'b'` and a row with `NULL` with no error. It's clear that I cannot afford another query to fetch the nullity of the value, but would prefer an error, in which case I would grow the `ENUM` definition like the following and repeat the query.

```
ALTER TABLE `enumed` CHANGE `col` `col` ENUM( 'a', 'b', 'z' );
INSERT INTO `enumed` ( `col`) VALUES ('b');
```

Is there any way to achieve this or is it just a painful way to handle a foreign collection that would require a table ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Also why are you using an enumeration ? It seems to me that they are pretty evil:
http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: So you add a value into `col` and if it doesn't exist in the `enum` you alter the table? I'm sorry but that doesn't make any sense at all. It means in conclusion any value is allowed in `enumed` (so you could just use a `varchar`) but it takes you so much more work to keep the table up-to-date.
I just don't see any advantage of using an `enum` here. Or did I miss something?

Comment: ENUMs take 1 byte to store, VARCHARs, in my example, is about an average 30 bytes, and I store millions of records. I just try to save as much space as possible

Comment: Depending on your use-case, it might make sense to create a separate lookup table, and `enumed` can store a surrogate identifier based on a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable strict SQL mode, attempting to store an invalid ENUM value will report an error. You could check for this error, extend the ENUM, and retry the INSERT.